# There are $n$ consecutive integers such that they are not prime powers

Tags: number-theory

I wanted to prove for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ,we have $n$ consecutive integers which are not prime powers by chinese remainder theorem.
I am not getting the approach. How to solve this?

Comment: Consider $3^1+1$  consecutive integers

Comment: Can you use the Chinese remainder theorem to find $x\in\mathbb N$ such that $x$ is divisible by $2\cdot3,$ $x+1$ is divisible by $5\cdot7$, $x+2$ is divisible by $11\cdot13,$ and $x+3$ is divisible by $17\cdot19?$

Comment: How can we configure thaT x is divisible by 2.3

Comment: Easy. Let $x=6t$ where $t\in\mathbb Z.$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the first 2n primes. Pair these up, so that you have n factors, each consisting of 2 primes. Now assume your starting number to be x.  For each pair of primes, let your desired starting number x be congruent to -k(ranging from 0 to n-1), modulo pair number. In conclusion, you need to find a x such that:

x = -1 mod(p1*p2)

x= -2 mod(p3*p2)

...

x=-k mod(pk*pk+1)

...

x= n-1 mod(p2n-1, p2n)

Which is possible due to Chinese Remainder Thereom

This solves the problem, since each of the n consecutive numbers will be divisible by at least 2 primes.